# How do I mimic the following c++ code using inline assembly?

Tags: c++, mutex, inline-assembly

I'm trying to mimic the following code using atomic inline assembly code:

```
struct Node{
    Node * next;
    int value;
}

typedef struct Node * Node_ptr;

Node_ptr store(Node_ptr ** L, Node_ptr * I){
    pthread_mutex_lock (&queue_mutex);
    Node_ptr tmp = **L; 
    **L = *I;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&queue_mutex)
    return tmp;
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
Node_ptr tmp;
__asm volatile ("lock; movq %1, %%rax; movq %%rax, %0"
                    : "=r" (tmp)
                    : "r" (**L)
                    : "%rax"
                    );

__asm volatile ("lock; movq %1, %%rax; movq %%rax, %0"
                    : "=r" (**L)
                    : "r" (*I)
                    : "%rax"
                    );
return tmp;
```

However I'm getting a "Illegal Instruction" error and I'm having trouble seeing where I went wrong. Does anyone have some insight as to what is the issue?

Thanks

Edit: added definition for node_ptr

Comment: The `lock` prefix is allowed on just a few instructions. `mov` is probably not one of those.

Comment: The example looks like C, not C++ code

Comment: It would help if we knew what a Node_ptr was defined as.

Comment: I think you want to use LOCK XCHG, but it depends on what Node_ptr is. Look at using the gcc atomic intrinsics to see if that helps out better: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 1):

Intel's manual says the following on the topic of the `LOCK` prefix:

> The LOCK prefix can be prepended only to the following instructions
>   and only to those forms of the instructions where the destination
>   operand is a memory operand: ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG,
>   CMPXCH8B, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD, and XCHG. If
>   the LOCK prefix is used with one of these instructions and the source
>   operand is a memory operand, an undefined opcode exception (#UD) may
>   be generated. An undefined opcode exception will also be generated if
>   the LOCK prefix is used with any instruc-tion not in the above list.

The best thing to do here (apart from reading the several thousand pages thick manuals from intel) is to look at what kind of output your compiler generates for the c++ code, that should give you an idea.

Comment: The compiler could just generate a `call pthread_mutext_lock`.  What he's interested in (I think) is what happens in that function; it _doesn't_ call into the OS unless there is contention.

Comment: @James True enough, but nothing stops you from just using a debugger and stepping into that.. well and that you may need to use KDB to get the really interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `CMPXCHG` instruction.  (You'll still need the `LOCK` prefix.)